# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^n (1+x_k^2)^n \leq 2^{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^n (1+x_k^{2n}) $

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have been trying to prove the inequality

> $$ \sum_{k=1}^n (1+x_k^2)^n \leq 2^{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^n (1+x_k^{2n})$$

using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality or even the general Holder inequality for different choices of $p$ and $q$ but thus far to no avail. It seems that I have been missing the correct choices of $p$ and $q$. Could you please give me some hints?

Thanks.

Comment: First summation index is $i$ or $k$?

Comment: @OriaGruber Typo, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to prove that, for every $n\geq 1$,
$$
(1+t)^n \leq 2^{n-1}(1+t^n),
\qquad \forall t\geq 0.
$$
Let us prove that the function
$$
\varphi(t) := 2^{n-1}(1+t^n) - (1+t)^n
$$
is non-negative in $[0,+\infty)$.
We have that
$$
\varphi'(t) = n 2^{n-1} t^{n-1} - n (1+t)^{n-1}
= n [(2t)^{n-1} - (1+t)^{n-1}],
$$
hence $\varphi'(t) \leq 0$ for $t\in [0,1]$, $\varphi'(t) \geq 0$ for $t\geq 1$,
so that $t = 1$ is an absolute minimum point for $\varphi$.
In conclusion
$$
\varphi(t) \geq \varphi(1) = 0
\qquad \forall t\geq 0.
$$

Comment: I like your solution, thank you.

Comment: The inequality follows a bit more quickly from Jensen inequality, since $\left(\frac{1+t}{2}\right)^n \leq \frac{1+t^n}{2}$.